# How can I make my dropdown list have a border radius on :hover?

Tags: html, css, hover

I have a drop down list which appears when you hover over the word 'shop'. I want the bottom of the drop down list to have a border-radius of 8px and it works but does not work on the very last `<li>` item which is the word 'storage'. How can I fix this? Visit this link to see it in action [www.me14ch.leedsnewmedia.net/slate](http://www.me14ch.leedsnewmedia.net/slate)

here is the code:

```
/* drop down list */

#navigation ul {
    list-style: none;
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    z-index: 2;
}

#navigation ul a {
    display: block;
    color: white;
    text-decoration: none;  
}

#navigation ul li {
    position: relative;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    width: 20%;
    display: inline-block;
    list-style-type: none;
    text-align: center;
    margin-left:-10px;
}

#navigation ul li:hover {
background:#6A8F28;
}

#navigation ul ul {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    top: 100%;
    left:0;
    background:#A3CC39;
    padding: 0;
    align-content: center;
    width: 100%;
    border-radius: 8px;
}

#navigation ul ul li {
    float: none;
    width: 100%;
    margin-left:0px;
}

#navigation ul ul a {
    line-height: 100%;
    padding: 10px 15px;
}

#navigation ul ul ul {
    top: 0;
    left: 100%;
}

#navigation ul li:hover > ul {
    display: block;
    border-radius:8px;
}
```

Comment: I can't even see the dropdown -- it appears behind your image carousel and items are hidden (Chrome OSX).

Answer (score 1):

This should do the trick - try it cheers

```
#navigation ul li:last-child a:hover {

    border-bottom-left-radius: 8px;
   border-bottom-left-radius: 8px;
}
```

Comment: I thought this would work but it didn't seem to :( thanks for trying to help though

Answer (score 0):

use `first-child` and `last-child`

```css
.nav{   
font-size:18px; 
font-weight: bold;
list-style:none;
margin:0;
padding:0;
text-align:center;
}

.nav li{
display:block; 
}

.nav a{
width: 144px;
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(rgb(256,256,256), rgb(175,175,175));
background:    -moz-linear-gradient(rgb(256,256,256), rgb(175,175,175));
background:         linear-gradient(rgb(256,256,256), rgb(175,175,175));
text-decoration:none;
display:inline-block;
padding:10px;
 }


.nav li:first-child > a {
border-radius: 20px 20px 0px 0px;
}
.nav li:last-child > a {
border-radius: 0px 0px 20px 20px;
}

.nav li:hover a{
    background: #222;
    color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<ul class="nav">
   <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">Couriers</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">Reviews</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">Retailers</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry try this one - that should work

```
#navigation ul ul  {

  border-bottom-left-radius: 8px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 8px;
  overflow: hidden; /* 1 */

}

/* 1. overflow: hidden is making sure when hover the bottom   will still be  rounded. remove this line and hover on the last item and see */
```